# Modifying an Images Enum

Tags: java, enums

So my friend crated this enum and i want to shorten it. I thought to shorting each of the file paths in strings and refrencing it `String pokemonPath = "Pictures/Menu/MainMenu/";` and then being like `pokePath +" Cosmet.png` but I'm not sure on how to implement it. Also if anyone has anyideas on how to shorten it more, i would love to hear it too. ALos its in its own class file so putting constants at the top will not work properly, it give me an error.

I don't really work with enums so i dont know how to use them efficiently.

This is his code

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public enum Images {

// Menu stuff. I don't know how to organize it. You do it.
WelcomeBG("Pictures/Menu/MainMenu/WelcomeBG.png"), PokemonTitleMenuBG(
        "Pictures/Menu/MainMenu/PokemonTitleMenuBG.png"), PokemonMenuAll(
        "Pictures/Menu/PokemonMenu/PokemonMenuAll.png"), PokemonMenuContinue(
        "Pictures/Menu/PokemonMenu/PokemonMenuContinue.png"), PokemonMenuContinueSelected(
        "Pictures/Menu/PokemonMenu/PokemonMenuContinueSelected.png"), PokemonMenuAllSelected(
        "Pictures/Menu/PokemonMenu/PokemonMenuAllSelected.png"), TitleScreen(
        "Pictures/Menu/MainMenu/TitleScreen.png"),

Professor("Pictures/Menu/NPC/Professor.png"), ProfessorFlip(
        "Pictures/Menu/NPC/ProfessorFlip.png"),

FriendGirl("Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/FriendGirl.png"), FriendBoy(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/FriendBoy.png"), PlayerBoy(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/PlayerBoy.png"), PlayerGirl(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/PlayerGirl.png"), Male(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/Male.png"), Female(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/Female.png"), Credits(
        "Pictures/Menu/MainMenu/Credits.png"), Gender(
        "Pictures/Menu/PlayerPictures/Gender.png"),

// Player sprites

PlayerDown("Pictures/Sprites/Player/"), PlayerDown1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Down1.png"), PlayerDown2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Down2.png"), PlayerLeft(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Left.png"), PlayerLeft1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Left1.png"), PlayerLeft2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Left2.png"), PlayerRight(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Right.png"), PlayerRight1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Right1.png"), PlayerRight2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Right2.png"), PlayerUp(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Up.png"), PlayerUp1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Up1.png"), PlayerUp2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/Up2.png"),

// NPC Sprites
DadDown("Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Dad/DadDown.png"), DadRight(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Dad/DadRight.png"), BoyLeft(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyLeft.png"), BoyRight(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyRight.png"), BoyRight1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyRight1.png"), BoyRight2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyRight2.png"), BoyUp(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyUp.png"), BoyUp1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyUp1.png"), BoyUp2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyUp2.png"), DadUp(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Dad/DadUp.png"), DadLeft(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Dad/DadLeft.png"),

GirlDown("Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Girl/GirlDown.png"), GirlRight(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Girl/GirlRight.png"), GirlLeft(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Girl/GirlLeft.png"), GateDown(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateDown.png"), GateLeft(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateLeft.png"), GateLeft1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateLeft1.png"), GateLeft2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateLeft2.png"), GateRight(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateRight.png"), GateRight1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateRight1.png"), GateRight2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Gate/GateRight2.png"), BoyDown(
        "Pictures/Sprites/NPC/Boy/BoyDown.png"),

// NPC Effects
Exclamation("Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Exclamation.png"),

// Maps (the background, base thing)
Exitium("Pictures/Maps/Exitium.png"), Route1("Pictures/Maps/Route1.png"), House1Top(
        "Pictures/Maps/House1Top.png"), House1Bot(
        "Pictures/Maps/House1Bot.png"), MiracleForest1(
        "Pictures/Maps/MiracleForest1.png"), MiracleForest2(
        "Pictures/Maps/MiracleForest2.png"),

// Map decorations (the stuff you code on top of the map!)
House1Overlay("Pictures/Sprites/Structures/House1Overlay.png"), House2Overlay(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/House2Overlay.png"), House3Overlay(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/House3Overlay.png"), House4Overlay(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/House4Overlay.png"), Lamppost(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/Lamppost.png"), MailBox(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/MailBox.png"), MailBox2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/MailBox2.png"), ColumnTrees(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/ColumnTrees.png"), Sign(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Sign.png"), GreenColumnTrees(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/GreenColumnTrees.png"), GreenColumnTrees2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/GreenColumnTrees2.png"), GreenColumnTrees3(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/GreenColumnTrees3.png"), ForestEntrance(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/ForestEntrance.png"), GreenTreeOverlay(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/GreenTreeOverlay.png"), LeftEntrance(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/LeftEntrance.png"), RightEntrance(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Structures/RightEntrance.png"),

// GUI Things???
Arrow("Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Arrow.png"), Hand(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Hand.png"), DialogBox(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/DialogBox.png"), DialogBox2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/DialogBox2.png"), DialogBox3(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/DialogBox3.png"), DialogBox4(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/DialogBox4.png"),

// I dont even know
MainBattleBack("Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/MainBattleBack.png"), Vs2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/Vs2.png"), MainHead(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/MainHead.png"),

// Battle Menu GUI things??
GreenBackground("Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/GreenBackground.png"), BattleMenu2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/BattleMenu2.png"), HpBarAlly(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/HpBarAlly.png"), HpBarEnemy(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/HpBarEnemy.png"), MoveMenu2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/MoveMenu2.png"),

// Natalie
Natalie("Pictures/Menu/NPC/Natalie.png"), NatalieHead(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/NatalieHead.png"), NatalieBattleBack(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/NatalieBattleBack.png"),

// Flashing
PlayerFlashNormal(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/Player_flash_normal.gif"), OpponentFlashNormal(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleStart/Opponent_flash_normal.gif"),

// Throwing Animation
MainThrow("Pictures/Sprites/Player/MainThrow.png"), MainThrow1(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/MainThrow1.png"), MainThrow2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Player/MainThrow2.png"),

// Attack Effects
Tackle("Pictures/Sprites/Battle/Attacks/Tackle.png"), BlackBack(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/Attacks/BlackBack.png"), Growl(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/Attacks/Growl.png"), Leer(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/Attacks/Leer.png"),

// POKEMONS
Cosmet("Pictures/Sprites/Pokemon/Cosmet.png"), CosmetB(
        "Pictures/Sprites/PokemonB/CosmetB.png"), CosmetStart(
        "Pictures/Menu/Starters/CosmetStart.png"),

Tykepol("Pictures/Sprites/Pokemon/Tykepol.png"), TykepolB(
        "Pictures/Sprites/PokemonB/TykepolB.png"), TykepolStart(
        "Pictures/Menu/Starters/TykepolStart.png"),

Embite("Pictures/Sprites/Pokemon/Embite.png"), EmbiteB(
        "Pictures/Sprites/PokemonB/EmbiteB.png"), EmbiteStart(
        "Pictures/Menu/Starters/EmbiteStart.png"),

// Balls
Pokeball("Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Pokeball.png"), Pokeball4(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Misc/Pokeball4.gif"),

// Outlines
Outline1("Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/Outline1.png"), Outline2(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/Outline2.png"), Outline3(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/Outline3.png"), Outline4(
        "Pictures/Sprites/Battle/BattleMenu/Outline4.png");

private String filePath;
private Image image;
private boolean imageLoaded;

private Images(String imagePath) {
    filePath = imagePath;
    imageLoaded = false;

}

public Image getImage() {
    if (!imageLoaded) {
        loadImage();
    }
    return image;

}

public void loadImage() {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load image!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageLoaded = true;
}
```

Comment: This seem to offer just the right amount of independence to the file paths...

Comment: @Thihara im not really sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, this kind of granularity is better for the purpose of storing image paths. Because you can move each images to whatever path you want. Generalizing will only limit your options... And force you to categorize images.. Also what if you have an image that falls into two categories? It's either replication of incorrect categorization!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you do will depend on what it is you want to achieve.

If you want to prevent the need to replace the path in multiple places should it change, then using `String` constants is a reasonable idea.

Something like...

```
public interface PathConstants {

    protected static final String SPRITES_PATH = "Pictures/Sprites";
    protected static final String SPRITES_MISC_PATH = SPRITES_PATH + "/Misc";
    protected static final String POKEMON_SPRITES_PATH = SPRITES_PATH + "/Pokemon";
    protected static final String POKEMONB_SPRITES_PATH = SPRITES_PATH + "/PokemonB";
    protected static final String STARTERS_MENU_PATH = "Pictures/Menu/Starters";
    protected static final String SPRITES_BATTLE_PATH = SPRITES_PATH + "/Battle";
    protected static final String MENU_BATTLE_PATH = SPRITES_BATTLE_PATH + "/BattleMenu";

}
```

Then you should be able to do something like...

```
public enum Images {
    Cosmet(PathConstants.SPRITES_PATH + "/Cosmet.png"), CosmetB(
           PathConstants.POKEMONB_SPRITES_PATH + "/CosmetB.png"), CosmetStart(
           PathConstants.STARTERS_MENU_PATH + "/CosmetStart.png"),

    Tykepol(PathConstants.POKEMON_SPRITES_PATH + "/Tykepol.png"), TykepolB(
            PathConstants.POKEMONB_SPRITES_PATH + "/TykepolB.png"), TykepolStart(
            PathConstants.STARTERS_MENU_PATH + "/TykepolStart.png"),

    Embite(PathConstants.POKEMON_SPRITES_PATH + "/Embite.png"), EmbiteB(
           PathConstants.POKEMONB_SPRITES_PATH + "/EmbiteB.png"), EmbiteStart(
           PathConstants.STARTERS_MENU_PATH + "/EmbiteStart.png"),

    // Balls
    Pokeball(PathConstants.SPRITES_MISC_PATH + "/Pokeball.png"), Pokeball4(
             PathConstants.SPRITES_MISC_PATH + "/Pokeball4.gif"),

    // Outlines
    Outline1(PathConstants.MENU_BATTLE_PATH + "/Outline1.png"), Outline2(
             PathConstants.MENU_BATTLE_PATH + "/Outline2.png"), Outline3(
             PathConstants.MENU_BATTLE_PATH + "/Outline3.png"), Outline4(
             PathConstants.MENU_BATTLE_PATH + "/Outline4.png");
```

For example.

This means that if the `SPRITES_PATH` changes, you only need to change it one place and recompile.

Comment: unfortuantely i cant put that at the beginning because it says "Cannot reference a field before it is defined"